# Nuxt.js -"export 'Toto' was not found in '~/components/Toto'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I try to create a component for a nuxtjs project.

I have a file called Toto.vue in components :

```
<template>
  <div>
      toto
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Toto'
}
</script>
```

In index.vue I want to use it then I have

In `<script>`

```
import { Toto } from '~/components/Toto'

export default {
  components: { Toto }
}
```

In `<template>`

```
<Toto />
```

In terminal when compiling I have this message :

```
"export 'Toto' was not found in '~/components/Toto'
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you did :

```
export default { ...
```

You should import it like :

```
import Toto  from '~/components/Toto'
```

or

```
import Toto  from '../components/Toto'
```